# How do I compile gtypist-2.9.5 on Alpine Linux?

Tags: compiling, alpine-linux, configure

[GNU Typist](https://www.gnu.org/software/gtypist/doc/gtypist.html) is a well-known typing practice program for the terminal. I wanted to use it so I downloaded the .tar.gz from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gtypist/?C=M;O=D. But when I untarred it and ran configure, it gives me the error

```
Error:  both library and header files for the ncursesw library are required to build this package.  See INSTALL file for further information. On Debian/Ubuntu you need to install libncursesw5-dev.
```

I already have ncurses and ncurses-dev installed (the branch is v3.15). I also tried installing ncurses5 and ncurses5-libs from branch v3.13 + ncurses-dev, but it shows me the same error. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I was being too pedantic with "everything must be managed by the package manager". In the configure file, the error was triggered by

```sh
if test -n "$HAVE_NCURSESW_H" -a -n "$HAVE_LIBNCURSESW";  then
   LIBS="-lncursesw $LIBS"
else
   echo -e "Error:  both library and header files for the ncursesw library\n"\
       "are required to build this package.  See INSTALL file for"\
       "further information. On Debian/Ubuntu you need to install libncursesw5-dev."
   exit 1;
fi
```

`HAVE_NCURSESW_H` is determined by these lines:

```sh
ac_fn_c_check_header_mongrel "$LINENO" "ncursesw/ncurses.h" "ac_cv_header_ncursesw_ncurses_h" "$ac_includes_default"
if test "x$ac_cv_header_ncursesw_ncurses_h" = xyes; then :
  HAVE_NCURSESW_H=1
fi
```

`ac_fn_c_check_header_mongrel` checks if a header exists.
So I created a folder named `ncursesw` in `/usr/include` (temporarily) and copied ncurses.h to the folder. Ran `configure` and everything worked perfectly after that.